# Portable monitors that work with Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: hardware, monitor

I was wondering if anyone had success in using a portable monitor on their Ubuntu system and if so which one?

Edit: (More details) Specifically I was thinking something along the lines of

[https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-MB168B-1366x768-Portable-Monitor/dp/B00FE690DI/ref=sr_1_4?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1535777031&sr=1-4&keywords=portable+monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FE690DI)

My system is a 2015 XPS 13 developer edition built to run Ubuntu.

Edit 2:  I ended up buying the usb monitor.  It was not plug and play out of the box but once I downloaded this:

http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1123

and then made the .run file executable and ran it, the monitor worked.

Update:  For ubuntu 19.04 the file to download is:

https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1304

One may have to disable paging to prevent crashes:

https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades

Comment: You might have to tell us more.  What do you mean by monitor?  cpu/hdd/motherboard temperature monitors? as I've not had issues reading any of this information, and my `conky` script shows monitored system temperatures/stats along with usual date, time etc. on my screen.  I didn't specifically add any monitors, just added `conky` to display them and modified by config file to display the info as I like.

Comment: Hi @guiverc I added more details, specifically I'm looking for portable USB powered monitors.

Comment: Interesting... what is "DisplayLink" and why do they provide the driver?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for hardware recommendations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I use one of those Asus monitors daily with my 2017 XPS 13, it works well.

I had to get to grips with xrandr and use 2x scaling on it.

I use mine in portrait orientation and unfortunately the supplied protective cover that doubles up as a stand does not work well as a stand in portrait, so I bought a folding plate stand off eBay that works admirably, and folds flat to maintain portability.

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04.
It will not fit in a 13" laptop bag for my XPS 13 but it does fit in a 15" laptop bag.

It's handy needing only one USB-C cable but it does make the laptop fans more likely to come on. Under simple editing they don't, but an app I use sometimes running under wine makes the fans come on after a few minutes when I have the monitor connected, but not otherwise. Nothing bad though...I use both daily.

Answer (score 0):

three years-ish later there is an Ubuntu driver on the ASUS site: Version 5.3.1 2020/06/1513.25 MBytes

MB Series USB Monitor Driver for Ubuntu
Support Ubuntu 20.04, 19.04 and 18.04 & Linux Kernel version range is from 4.15 to 5.5.
(No need to install driver if you using Type C video signal output)
When connecting with USB 3.0 mode, certain content or apps with security protection on host devices may prohibit the viewing of protected content on MB series monitor. If you have paid media content on your device, it is possible your app may limit its viewing to your host device only.

click here:  https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Monitors/MB168B/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: I"m about to buy this so hope it works.