# Can't connect ASUS ZenScreen MB16AC in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, hardware, asus, displaylink

I'm trying to install and connect my ASUS ZenScreen MB16AC to my Kubuntu PC and I already tried the steps in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071047/portable-monitors-that-work-with-ubuntu-linux) and this [page](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=asus-mb16ac-zenscreen&num=2) but unfortunately my monitor still can't connect.
As a proof, here's the screenshot of when I tried to reinstall the DisplayLink 5.1 again:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgyMY.png)

Am I missing something or is there any other way to do it?
Any advises will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Elia,
If you are using a fresh install of ubuntu 18.10 - don't upgrade to the very latest patch. My display link (5.1) was working until I upgraded to the patch released last week.

Comment: Noted @Falieson I'll make sure of it

Comment: Hi guys, this problem is already solved by following this guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink